# A working tf_agents.agents.PPOClipAgent example for reference?

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I am really struggling on finding a working example for tf_agents.agents.PPOClipAgent, for instance for the simple CartPoleV1 environment. Does anybody have one or a link to a good example? I tried to use it but it doesn't learn anything so I wrong for sure something. Thank you.